# How to use JS to target specific domain html <a> links with CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use online note taking editors to take notes. One of them I'm using is called dynalist.io.

I run stylebot (chrome plugin) to apply specific CSS sheets to those pages

Normally when i put a URL link inside of my documents, I put two types:

- Imgur.com links
- Any other domain links

I'd like to apply CSS styles on those `<a href>` tags seperately, however the program defaults the same class for all domain links so I cannot use CSS classes to achieve this

unless (to my knowledge) use javascript to target `<a href>` and make seperate classes for different domain links. Then apply CSS rules

Reference image:

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

edit: would I have to use greasemonkey to inject javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following rules at your css file (this is not efficient):

```
a[href^="http://i.imgur.com"] {
    color: red !important;
}
```

It is like a regexp, and it is not efficient for a standard css, but in your case... will be good.

EDIT:
The `!important` is just to make sure you will overwrite other css rules.
The regexp is not efficient (for big pages) because the css need to check all the `<a>` tag and make a control.

If you need to change the color of other links, you need to create the same rule but with another link.

Comment: this works for me http://i.imgur.com/30JT7CK.png.  css files. http://i.imgur.com/b0TAnau.png.  Also, what is the major downside to using this method? I assume `!important` is to give higher priority, but what happens if i had two special cases? Like one for imgur.com links, another for gyfcat.com links for example?

Comment: The downside of this method is the regexp. In a huge page this method is slower than using a class selector (it take few ms more to render). 
Because the css need to process all the <a> tag and make a control.

Comment: And the import method is to overwrite the other rules  (because I don't know where you'll put the css file).
If you need to mark, in different color, more link you have to create for each link a rule with regexp notation. In the other case, you have to add the case in the same rules

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you want to select all links who are from imgur and add a class to them.

You could do it like this:

Select all the **a** elements whose **href** attributes contains **imgur**.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="imgur"]');
```

Add the class 'sup' to them:

```
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.add('sup');
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the code into tampermonkey but its not adding the sup class for some reason http://i.imgur.com/2Iw85tk.png.